# Iterating over Objects in Ember handles bar

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have created an Object in my ember App and have created some instances of it. Now I want to retrieve that data and display it in the handlesbar template. Is there any way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your structure is kind of this example

```
App.MyObject = Ember.Object.extend({
  // some attributes
  anyAttribute: DS.attr()
});

App.MyRoute = App.Route.extend({
   model: function(){
    // return your object array
   }

});
```

In your template:

```
{{#each item in model}}
  {{item.anyAttribute}}
{{/each}}
```